# Efficiently looping through Python excluding the current element

Tags: python, loops, iteration

When iterating through a list, I want to keep track of the current element and then apply a function to the remaining elements.

For example, the first iteration will print out **red** and the **apply_function** will be called passing **blue, green and black**.

The second iteration will print out **blue** and **apply_function** will be called passing **red, green and black**.

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black']

for color in colors:
    print color
        ### iterate through everything EXCEPT the current color
        apply_function(other_colors)
```

Comment: Do you mean `apply_function([c for c in colors if c != color])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method to do this is:

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black']

for i, color in enumerate(colors):
    print color
    ### iterate through everything EXCEPT the current color
    apply_function(colors[:i] + colors[i+1:])
```

This will only exclude the current index, and will work if you have duplicate entries.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very slick.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by:

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black']

for index,color in enumerate(colors):
    print (color)
    apply_function(colors[:index] + colors[index+1:])
```

Comment: Thank you. This is terrific smooth way. I am new to Python and this is very slick.

Answer (score 0):

iterate over the indices; make a copy; pop an item from the copy.

```
>>> indices = range(len(colors))
>>> apply_f = print
>>> for i in indices:
    c = colors[:]
    apply_f(c.pop(i), c)


red ['blue', 'green', 'black']
blue ['red', 'green', 'black']
green ['red', 'blue', 'black']
black ['red', 'blue', 'green']
>>>
```